# Hot to insert a different img into a div depending on the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

I am trying to insert a img into a div, but it should be a different img depending on the div value, which is dynamically populating

So if value is test insert image test.jpg, if the value is blabla insert image blabla.jpg and so on (i got about 25 div values)

I got it working only for the first one now and it is only populating one img everywhere if i use

```
var divText = $('div').first().text();
```

My names vars and the img names jpg are exactly the same

Probably need to loop it somehow, some help will be appreciate

My code so far is

HTML

```
<div>test</div>
<div>blabla</div>
<div>dasdad</div>
<div>khjkhjk</div>
```

jQuery

```
var name = 'test';
var name1 = "blabla";
var imgPath = "folder/images/";
var divText = $('div').text();
   if (divText === name) {
   $('div').prepend('<img src="' + imgPath + 'test' + '.jpg"/>');
   }
   if (divText === name1) {
   $('div').prepend('<img src="' + imgPath + 'blabla' + '.jpg"/>');
   }
```

Here is my fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6da9jvr7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with jquery's each.

```
$('div').each(function(){
  var $div = $(this);
  $div.prepend(<img src="' + imgPath + $div.text() + '.jpg"/>');
});
```

When you call `$('div').each()`, jquery first selects every div in the document. It then loops over the divs and calls the callback you specify. "this" is bound to the current div in the loop, so when we call $(this) we're "wrapping" that div with jquery, which allows us to use functions like .text and .prepend.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `each` loop for this

```
$.each($('div'), function() {
    var img_name = $(this).text();
    $(this).prepend('<img src="' + imgPath + img_name + '.jpg"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple assumptions in [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6da9jvr7/1/) (added the `foo` class to the divs, etc)

I believe all you need is this:

```
var imgPath = "folder/images/";

$('div.foo').each(function(index, element){
   var divText = $(element).text();
    $('div').prepend('<img src="' + imgPath + divText + '.jpg"/>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could identify the divs another way by adding a class for example:

```
<div class="dynamic-image">test</div>
<div class="dynamic-image">blabla</div>
```

Now you can just search all divs with the `dynamic-image` class, and fetch the image based on content, like so:

```
var path = 'path/to/images';

$('.dynamic-image').each(function(i, e) {
    var $e = $(e),
        img = new Image();

    img.src = path + '/' + $e.text() + '.jpg';
    $e.prepend(img);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the looping part, you can do something like this. Note that you want to use innerHTML and not text. Also, keeping in mind that $('div') returns an array of divs (which I set to the variable divs).

```
var divs = $('div');

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    alert(divs[i] + "   " + divs[i].innerHTML);
}
```